# Edit an old commit message with git filter-branch

Tags: git

In a case I want to fully edit a particular commit, I use the following command:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
"if test \$GIT_COMMIT = '5b740c488f0e4251a6e534cab79da8b05de7a195'
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='John Doe'
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='John Doe'
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='john.doe@gmail.com'
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='john.doe@gmail.com'
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='1493100264'
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='1493100264'
fi"
```

**Is there a way to edit the commit message too ?**

I'm aware I can mix `--msg-filter` with `sed`, but if multiple commits have the same commit message, that could be a problem.

What I'd like is a way to tell "For this SHA, set the commit message as X", similar to the way I edit author and commit date

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know how to test in an `--env-filter`.  All you need to realize, then, is that [`--msg-filter` is used in the very same place as `--env-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e2cb6ab84c94f147f1259260961513b40c36108a/git-filter-branch.sh#L353-L403):<sup>1</sup>

> ```
>     eval "$filter_env" < /dev/null ||
>             die "env filter failed: $filter_env"
>     ...
>     {
>             while IFS='' read -r header_line && test -n "$header_line"
>             do
>                     # skip header lines...
>                     :;
>             done
>             # and output the actual commit message
>             cat
>     } <../commit |
>             eval "$filter_msg" > ../message ||
>                     die "msg filter failed: $filter_msg"
> ```

The default value of `$filter_env` is empty, but this is replaced by your `--env-filter` argument.  The default value of `$filter_msg` is `cat`; this is similarly replaced by your `--msg-filter` argument.

Both are `eval`ed directly, in an environment in which `$GIT_COMMIT`, `$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, and so on are all set.  Since `filter_msg` is eval-ed on the right hand side of a pipeline, *changes* to the environment variables are lost (so you must make any desired changes in the other filter), but you can still *inspect* them.  Since `$filter_env` is run first, you must consider that any changes you made there are in effect by the time your `$filter_msg` gets run.

Hence:

> What I'd like is a way to tell "For this SHA, set the commit message as X", similar to the way I edit author and commit date.

translates into:

```
--msg-filter 'if test $GIT_COMMIT = 5b740c488f0e4251a6e534cab79da8b05de7a195;
     then cat >/dev/null && cat $HOME/tmp/prepared-msg; else cat; fi'
```

or similar.  (The `cat >/dev/null` is a bit of paranoia here to discard stdin to avoid broken pipe errors.  If you use `sed` to edit the message, don't discard stdin.)

---

<sup>1</sup>I am not sure why the `git-filter-branch.sh` code uses a `{ while ... }` loop to strip the headers from the commit, when `sed -e '1,/^$/d'` would suffice. ... Ah, I may remember why: some `sed`s demand that messages end with a final newline, perhaps.  Yes, that's why: [see commit df0620108b9710a06d5a2d9c125d43b97590cce6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df0620108b9710a06d5a2d9c125d43b97590cce6))

Comment: Great answer, very complete! Thanks a lot

Comment: Why did you use `cat $HOME/tmp/prepared-msg` ? Using `echo` works well too

Comment: That lets you write a long message.  One-line commit messages are rarely very good.

Comment: Thank you! especially the snippet from the git source code was very illustrative!

Answer (score 1):

So, if anyone is looking for a working command, here is the one I use:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter \
"if test \$GIT_COMMIT = '5b740c488f0e4251a6e534cab79da8b05de7a195'
then 
    echo 'New commit message!\nOn multiple lines'; else cat
fi"
```

Comment: small note: I had to use `echo -e` for the '\n' to function properly.
This is in GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release